# EmguCV video capture for raw bayer camera

Tags: c#, opencv, video-capture

I'm using Visual Studio 11 and `EmguCV` libraries, and I'm trying to capture images from camera. The `Emgu.CV.Capture` function works perfectly, when I use in-build or usb RGB camera but when I want to capture from `See3CAM_10CUG_CBX` camera(which is a raw bayer camera) the Capture function had stopped working.
I already have installed the cameras driver.
When I enable native code debugging I get these errors:

```
Bayer_Transform_Filter.dll 1, 0,13,e_CAMVIEW_SVN_VERSION
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\Bayer_Transform_Filter.pdb:Cannot find or open the PDB file.
E:\E-CAMView\Oct21(Solving Moniker issue in eCAM1M_CUGUSB)\Release\Bayer_Transform_Filter.pdb:Cannot find or open the PDB file.
C:\Windows\symbols\dll\Bayer_Transform_Filter.pdb:Cannot find or open the PDB file.
C:\Windows\dll\Bayer_Transform_Filter.pdb:Cannot find or open the PDB file.
C:\Windows\Bayer_Transform_Filter.pdb:Cannot find or open the PDB file.
```

Do you have any idea how can I fix this problem, or any idea how to capture frames from raw bayer in Visual Studio C# because EmguCV's Capture function doesnt work?

Answer (score 0):

1.You can use the camera's SDK written in C#.

2.If the camera support 'directshow' driver, you can install it and use EmguCV to try.

3.If the camera support 'directshow' driver, you can install it and us 'DirectShowLib in .net' to make it work.